# How do I require the specification of term in a custom post type and custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a post type called `fi`. For that I have a custom taxonomy called `fi_types`. `fi_types` contains 5 terms.

How do I **require** a user to specify at least one term within this taxonomy? Preferably the `Other` term.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you simply want to add the `Other` term to the post if the user hasn't added any terms?  Would that solution work for you?

Comment: @LinneaHuxford Yes that will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something similar at the moment. I've decided on using radio buttons or a dropdown to ensure a user has to pick from my taxonomy terms when creating their post.

I'm still refinig my solution, but these two articles have helped me a lot:

http://themefoundation.com/wordpress-meta-boxes-guide/

I want my metabox to appear in multiple post types so I've used this too:

https://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/add-meta-box-to-multiple-post-types

Hope this helps. I will endeavour to update if I change the example code in the articles significantly.

Comment: Seems like it'd be a lot easier to just use Advanced Custom Fields for this. I'm already using ACF for the site. In it I could simply add a taxonomy field and make it required. However I would have to hide the normal box (in order to prevent the user from specifying the same thing twice) and that's not ideal. I wanna use the default meta box for the terms.